# General: Show a matrix is nilpotent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Where the matrix does not appear to be upper triangular?
How do I go about doing this?

Comment: If you have an expression for the matrix, you could simple calculate its square, and its cube, and its fourth power, etc, and hopefully one of these will be zero.

Comment: $A^n=0$ for some $n$ so your minimal polynomial divides $t^n-1$. In other words, all your eigenvalues are $n$-th roots of unity. So you can look at what your eigenvalues are.

Comment: @daruma: No, if $A$ is nilpotent then $0$ is the only eigenvalue.

Comment: @daruma The only possible eigenvalue of a nilpotent matrix is zero. And not all nilpotent matrices are diagonalisable.

Comment: @carmichael561 Oh yes, $A^n=0$ means that the minimal polynomial is $t^n$ not $t^n-1$. So the eigenvalues are all $0$. Kenny Wong,  I didn't say anything about the matrix being diagonalizable.

Comment: @daruma No, $A^n=0$ does not mean either that the minimal polynomial is $t^n$.